# Shiny: environment variables vs. reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny, environment-variables, reactive-programming

I'm building an app that frequently modifies a data.frame.

In this app, I have a variable created with reactiveValues with three data.frames: raw, modified and final. Modified are always changing and final is updated after modified is ok.

They aren't necessarily reactive yet, though. Being that the case, is there any difference between using a reactive value over an environment variable? Example:

```
var <- new.env()
var$a <- data.frame()
```

vs

```
var <- reactiveValues()

# Random observeEvent
  var$a <- data.frame()
```

Really confused about when to use an environment variable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, do you want the object to be reactive or not? You should describe the behavior you want and that will help decide what you need to do to achieve it. I can't think of any good reason to use an "environment variable" like that in a Shiny app. Did you get that suggestion from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed I agree with you. I have seen an app (very good) similar to mine that does use environment variable over reactive value to manage the state of a data.frame and that got me thinking to where should I use environment variables in a Shiny App.

Eventually I might indeed need reactivity, but is that really the only thing to consider?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does this app use reactive inputs?  Have you tried to use reactive inputs outside a reactive environment?

Comment: At the moment, I render a DataTable based on the reactive data.frame. That could be easilly changed by reacting a reactive function that extracts the data.frame from an environment variable, if needed.

Comment: @Edgar Can you share a bit of working copy-pastable code (inspired from the app you saw or not) that uses environment variables instead of reactive values in the context of Shiny? (you got me (us?) intrigued